# Self Signed Certificate in certificate chain discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am coding a discord bot and had this issue i have been unable to fix this issue i'm running npm 8.10.0

code
Bot token is in code but i have not included it here

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const bot = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
})

const time = new Date()


bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Algorith Established " + time);
})

bot.login(token)


bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'BadWordImmune')){
        return
    } else {
        if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('p')){
            message.member.roles.add()
        }
    }
})
```

Terminal output

```
***@Haliday folder % node index.js
/Users/***/code/folder/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:201
        throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request);
              ^

HTTPError [FetchError]: request to https://discord.com/api/v9/gateway/bot failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/***/code/folder/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:201:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/Users/***/code/folder/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async WebSocketManager.connect (/Users/***/code/folder/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:134:9)
    at async Client.login (/Users/***/code/folder/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:254:7) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'get',
  path: '/gateway/bot',
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

Comment: Likely you're talking to a fake server; are you on a network where data is 'inspected' like a business or school, or you must authenticate like a hotel 'portal', or do you have antivirus or similar 'endpoint' software? discord.com uses Cloudflare so depending on your location it's conceivable you're getting a misconfigured instance, but less likely. Try `openssl s_client -connect discord.com:443 -servername discord.com` and see if you get `s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Cloudflare, Inc./CN=sni.cloudflaressl.com
   i:/C=US/O=Cloudflare, Inc./CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3`.

Comment: That was the issue thanks for the advice